# Is there a 'bottom-to-top' equivalent of the unicode 'rtl override'?

Tags: text, unicode, formatting

I often need text to wrap above the previous line rather than below.

```
above the ones before it.     ^
where each new line goes      |
from the top to the bottom,   
that reads in this direction, ^
for example, a piece of text  |
```

In Unicode, there are various 'rtl' overrides for when you want to have characters being displayed right to left, but I can't find anything for a 'bottom-to-top' or 'low-to-high' override.

Is there something I'm missing or is this just not a common problem?